# teradata - volatile table

Tags: sql, teradata, temp-tables, sql-tuning, global-temp-tables

2 Questions

- I populated a volatile table with couple of million rows and am
  running a query via bteq on a Solaris Client ( so it runs regardless
  of  my workstation connection) . Now If I see the run time explain
  stuck at some step , I want to abort just the query without loosing
  my session and VT contents how can this be done without admin privs.

  - Where are Stats stored for a VT and How can I  indirectly access them or get a hint

Comment: Please visit the [help] and review the guidelines for asking questions.  Hint: one question to a post, and include your code and a detailed explanation of what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1874594 : you didn't specified which mode you are interactive or batch 
 if you query is running for a long time in interactive mode , you can do below
 press control+C 
 `BREAK received. Input Command:` [after pressing break key or control C]

and then fire ABORT . You will get below screen.

```
abort;
 *** ABORT signal received.
 *** Warning: Canceling the rest of the output.
 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
```

your VT table is still there..:)

2)  VT tables  are stored in SPOOL and there stats are collected in memory. You can't access them directly.
Help stats is the only way .

By the way if you have script experience then write a shell script and get that stats in a file.

Comment: I always do ^C but it quits the BTEQ completely. I guess the key is JUST one ^C. Twice & you are out

Comment: Press cntrl+c  for once only...then it will show like BREAK received. Input Command: then write abort only

Comment: RIght on. I use to do this all the time but I never really had a situation where my VT  was just preceding ^C to abort in bteq. Most times I ended up using SQL ass abort, which will keep VT. I assumed this would but I wanted to check for sure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231402/multiple-table-aliases-between-fact-and-dimension-teradata